# Как установить нужный шрифт для текста на кнопках?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button, шрифты

Как на языке программирования *Python* в библиотеке *tkinter* сделать разные шрифты на кнопки?

Вот весь код:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile, asksaveasfile


root = Tk()
root.title('Заметки')
root.geometry('400x400')

text = Text(root,width=400, height=400)
text.pack()

menu_bar = Menu(root)
file_menu = Menu(menu_bar)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label='Файл', menu = file_menu)

file_name = NONE

def new_file():
    global file_name
    file_name = "Без названия"
    text.delete(1.0, END)

def save_as():
    out = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
    data = text.get('1.0', END)
    try:
        out.write(data.rstrip())
    except Exception:
        messagebox.showerror("Ой! Не хорошо...", "Я дал тебе ложную  надежду... Файл нельзя сохранить!")

def open_file():
    global file_name
    inp = askopenfile(mode = 'r')
    if inp is None:
        return
        file_name = inp.name
    data = inp.read()
    text.delete('1.0', END)
    text.insert('1.0' , data)

file_menu.add_command(label="Новый",command=new_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Сохранить как...", command=save_as)
file_menu.add_command(label="Открыть",command=open_file)

root.config(menu=menu_bar)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
class Window:
    def __init__(self,toplevel):
        self.fr1 = Frame(toplevel)
        self.fr1.pack()

        self.btn1 = Button(self.fr1,text='Привет!')
        self.btn1['background']='green'
        self.btn1['font']=('Verdana','12','italic','bold')
        self.btn1['fg']='yellow'
        self.btn1['height']=3
        self.btn1.pack()

        self.btn2 = Button(self.fr1,bg='red', font=('Times','16'))
        self.btn2['text']='До свидания!'
        self.btn2['fg']='blue'
        self.btn2['width']=12
        self.btn2.pack()

root=Tk()
Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]